# Showing a part of an image in HTML 5

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

Consider I have an image containing 100 icons with size of 16x16. So the image size is 1600x16.
Now I want to have an `HTML 5` tag to show the `nth` image.
What's the HTML syntax to define a specific part of image to show

```
<img src="pic.jpg" height="16" width="16" offsetOrSomething=??/>
```

Comment: AFAIK, this can't be done in HTML, only CSS. And note that "CSS3" isn't really a meaningful term, as there is no single standard bearing that version number, just a bunch of different "modules" with their own versions, and more importantly, the often-partial implementations in various browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the image as a background and use the `background-position` to move it..

```
<span class="icon nth"></span>
```

and

```
.icon{
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-image: url('pic.jpg');
}
.icon.nth{
  background-position:-32px -16px; /*both left and top should be multiples of the icon dimensions*/
}
```

---

If you ***have*** to do it like in your example, then you would need a wrapper again that is `overflow:hidden` and then move the image inside it..

```
<span class="icon-wrapper"><img src="pic.jpg" style="left:-16px;top:-32px;" /></span>
```

and

```
.icon-wrapper{
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.icon-wrapper img{position:absolute;}
```

Comment: just noticed that your icons are in horizontal sequence only.. so you should set the top in both cases to `0` and just move the left by multiples of -16

Answer (score -1):

A simple way is constraining the dimensions of the parent to crop the image...

```
<div style="height:10px; overflow-y:hidden;">

    <img src="pic.jpg" height="16" width="16" />

</div>
```

Try setting the margin top to a negative value to see the hidden part.